# Как создать список (массив) который будет получать Id пользователей написавших сообществу

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Просматривал документацию и знаю что именно мне нужно "count и profiles" но я не могу понять как правильно это прописать в самом коде.

Цель отправлять сообщения (Методом рассылки) людям которые писали в сообщения группы

Comment: Вопрос можно улучшить описав методы vk-api, что использовали. Приведя ваш код. И что у вас не получается

Comment: Я не использовал пока что никаких методов, я просто проконсультировал документацию и узнал какие именно методы используются для определённых действий, мой вопрос заключается в том что бы узнать как эти методы прописать в коде 

При прописи например ответа на сообщение мой код выглядит вот так :
            if response == "привет":
                api.messages.send(peer_id=event.obj.peer_id or event.message.peer_id, message="Приветики", keyboard=keyboard, random_id=0)